# Changing external IP address only of one program

Tags: windows, networking, ip

I play a random online game. It allows only one user per IP. How can I change my IP per one instance/program, in other words, How can I change the external IP Address only of one program, so I can open different instances of the game with different external IP Addresses?
Btw, I want to open the instances on the same computer(windows 11).

Comment: You might test to ensure they truly restrict per IP by trying to connect on the same computer with two different browsers just in case. Connect with Chrome then with Edge or FireFox and see if they are truly blocking per public IP address connection. Otherwise, you'd need to run VMs and VPN connection or use Tor or something like that. Not sure how you'd control from the same Windows 11 OS for different connections to hop to the game servers via different hops to change the IP without affecting all connections though, getting a bit complex if that's even possible but it's like complex if so.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change the external IP Address only of one program,

You cannot change this from a workstation.

You might be able to change it in your router (only possibly).  More likely the external IP address is assigned by your ISP and they are not likely to change it for you.

There is a good possibility the game makers also identified your computer (MAC address or like) to prevent what you are trying to do.

Long answer.

Short answer:  No, you cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a VPN product to give your computer a new IP address situated
anywhere in the world where there are located VPN servers of this product.

Each location will give you a different IP address from the chosen country.

Free VPN products exist, but commercial ones may give better results.